# `tidyverse` package in R not loading due to `cli` version

Tags: r, tidyverse

I was received the following error when trying to load the `tidyverse` package in R in Rstudio (no other packages were throwing an error)

```
Loading required package: tidyverse
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
```

I tried the following

- Restarting Rstudio
- `install.packages('cli')`
- Opening the command prompt as admin and navigating to `C:\Program Files\R\<R version>\bin\x64` and running R there with `R.exe` there, the running `install.packages('cli')`

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I selected the "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" when I posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked was navigating to `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\R\win-library\<version>` and deleting the `cli` folder. Then opening Rstudio as normal and running `install.packages('cli')`